# How did "sinister", the Latin word for "left-handed", get its current meaning?

Tags: meaning, etymology, loanwords, latin

*Sinister* is the Latin word for *left-handed*.  What evolution of meaning turned *left-handed* into *evil* and *threatening*?

Comment: Even relatively modern use of left=awkwardness in skateboarding, propelling a skateboard with the left foot whilst facing left is called 'skating goofy'. I'm also not that old but my sister was reprimanded at school for writing left handed (in the late 1980's!). I'm ambidextrous, a professional computer programmer and an amateur magician, so I reckon I'd have been burnt as a witch back in the day. :) Isn't language fascinating!

Comment: @WizardSleeve: probably comes (via surfing) from Disney: see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/64470/8019.

Comment: Are you asking about meaning of the word in English, Latin or what? The word had both meanings in Latin since forever and in Italian too (since 13th century), but meanings could have followed different paths in English.

Comment: @Nemo That is interesting. I wonder which language first normalized the use of "sinister" with the meaning "evil".

Comment: @Daniel Latin itself https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sinister#Latin If you mean what language/people first associated the concept of "left" to "bad", Greeks came before it seems, but I guess it would soon become a paleoanthropology question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the past, to be left-handed was considered [touched by the Devil](http://www.anythinglefthanded.co.uk/lh-info/myths.html). As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-handedness) notes:

> Historically, the left side, and subsequently left-handedness, was considered negative in many cultures. The Latin word sinistra originally meant "left" but took on meanings of "evil" or "unlucky" by the Classical Latin era, and this double meaning survives in European derivatives of Latin, and in the English word "sinister".
>
> Meanings gradually developed from use of these terms in the ancient languages. In many modern European languages, including English, the word for the direction "right" also means "correct" or "proper", and also stands for authority and justice. In most Slavic languages the root prav is used in words carrying meanings of correctness or justice.

So, if you were left-handed or *sinister*, you were associated with evil. In time, *sinister* itself meant *evil* and *threatening*. [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sinister) said that *sinister* attained this meaning in the early 15th century. The OED supports this, writing that the first uses of *sinister* to mean *malicious* were:

> 1474    Rolls of Parl. VI. 110/1   Contynuyn in habundaunce of goodes and havour, to their sinister pleasure.
>
> 1477    Earl Rivers tr. Dictes or Sayengis Philosophhres (Caxton) (1877) lf. 7,   Leste ye be let or withdrawen ther fro by eny sinistre or euil temptacion.

Comment: I'm a southpaw. Reading this made by back cold.

Comment: EtymOnline is wrong. See the example I added to https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sinister#Latin

Answer (score 27):

This goes back to the art of divination the early Romans named *avspecium* (coined after *aves* "birds" and *specio* "I watch" => *specious*).  Bird-watching the Roman way so to speak.

One way [auspices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haruspex) would use to guess good and bad omens was to watch which direction some [auspicious](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=auspicious) types of birds like ravens, crows or eagles were flying by.  These birds were supposed to play the role of messengers of the gods.  [Here](http://www.novaroma.org/nr/Auspicium) is a nice study of this type of divination.

This was also practised in Ancient Greece and named [οἰωνίζομαι (ornithomancy)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithomancy).

If birds were flying by on your right this was good omen. On the **left** (**sinistra**) that was **bad omen**.

The word *sinistre* was already a synonym of bad omen in Old French but had lost the meaning of "left" when it was introduced into Middle English.

In Italian though it still has both meanings.

**Edit**
As FumbleFinger rightly observes, right handed people have a natural tendency to associate negative sensations to their left-hand side.  Yet the question was about the word *sinister* which can be traced back to Latin.

The etymological path, as far as I understand it, is as follows:

**1a.**  Early Ancient Greek *σκαιὀς*, "left, awkward, ill-omen",
  **1b.**  Latin *scaevus*, "left, ill-omen",
  **2.**    Latin *sinister*, "on the left hand side, ill-omen",
  **3.**    Old French *senestre*/*sinistre*, "sinister" occasionally "awkward". 
          Left is already *gauche* in the 13th century - origin obscure,
  **4.**    Middle English ca 1400: *sinister* "unfavourable", "deceitful, prejudicial, dishonest".

Also consider the following points:

- A considerable number of languages have the "awkward" sense associated with the word for "left" but very few of them also have the sense of "ill omen".
- The Latin public and private life was heavily influenced by superstitions. For instance the reason why the Roman calendar evolved from lunar to solar is   because of the drift accumulated by having only 29 and 31 days months. An even number of days per month was ill-omen, so that there were no 30 days months before the Julian calendar.
- Now that divination is much less prevalent, most Romance languages (Spanish, Portuguese, French and Romanian for instance) have lost the coupling between left and ill-omen (but still retain the *awkward* sense).

Another curiosity I'd like to mention is that the aforementioned Early Ancient Greek word for left (*σκαιὀς*, "skaios") and its Latin cognate (*scaevus*) seem to come from a Proto Indo European root for *shadow* (same etymology actually as "shadow" itself): (PIE *skeh<sub>2</sub>-i-uo-, via Pt Italic *skaiwo) which is to compare to several other Indo European languages (various Celtic languages, Greek, Lithuanian, Sanskrit, Avestan) in which **right-hand side** also means **southwards**.

There is a lot of evidence suggesting that ancient Indo Europeans and Semites **orient**ated themselves facing eastwards (like old maps do) because this is where the sun rises in the morning.

In the northern hemisphere, when one faces eastwards the sun is always on the right-hand side and one's shadow is thus always on the left-hand side, which explains the relation in some antique words for *left* with similar words for *shadow*.

Comment: In Italian, _sinistro_ has also the meaning of _accident_; it's famous the joke _uomo perde braccio destro in un incidente; polizia indaga sul sinistro_ ("man loses the right arm in a crash; police investigate on the [left arm/accident]").

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Since the word *sinister* is from Latin origin I did not dig deeper in the past.  I've added some considerations in my last edits (some conjectural) hinting at the fact that the custom was already reported in Homer (in both Ill. and Od.).

Comment: I've deleted my earlier comment, since it's now superfluous. I appreciate you're primarily addressing the etymology of *sinister*. But I can't let *most Romance languages have lost the coupling between left and ill-omen* go unchallenged, I'm afraid. I'm assuming "ill-omen" is just one example of "negative things". You will know better than me, of course, but does not the French use of "gauche" include the English meaning? Certainly the antonym "droit" can be used in relation to "positive/powerful/correct things".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Romance language do follow the universal pattern of left = awkward and right = correct/just. But the ill-omen connotation which is quite a different thing is now mostly decoupled.   In this [useful catalogue](http://www.anythingleft-handed.co.uk/lefty_language.html) of translations for left handed there are few occurrences of "ill omen".

Comment: If that etymological path is a _path_, make it with a numbered list, it will be clearer. Just a note. :D

Comment: @Alenanno, ecco fatto! But the Greek and Latin words are probably just cognates.  Hence the 1a./1b. numbering scheme.  It's very difficult to decide.

Comment: @Alain: Oh well that is up to you! :D I was just saying that it could help people to "visualize" it already as a sequence, let's say... :D

Comment: This is incorrect. Sinister is good for romans, bad for Greeks. See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sinister#Latin

Comment: @Nemo, You're quite right. Please have a look at Ernout Meillet 2001, Dictionnaire Etymologique de la langue latine 4eme Ed. p628.
"Comming from the left, that is to say favourable or on the contrary defavourable, depending on whether one follows the Etrusco-Roman interpretation, facing South with East on the left hand side or the Greek interpretation, facing Northwards, with East on the right hand side. **The latter acceptation is the most frequent**".
All in all, the East (cf. sun rise and Spring equinox) is the auspicious direction.

Comment: @Nemo, the original text for your reference reads in frech as follows: ""qui vient du côté gauche", c'est à dire favorable, ou, au contraire, sinistre, défavorable selon qu'on interprète le présage d'après le rite etrusco romain, c'est-à-dire la face tournée vers le Sud avec l'Est à sa gauche, ou suivant le rite grec c'est a dire la face tournée vers le Nord, avec l'Est à sa droite, (cf. scaeuus) **c'est le dernier sens qui est le plus fréquent**, cf. Cic., Diu. 2, 39, 82; 2, 35, 74- Varron cité par Fest. 454."

Answer (score 10):

I'm surprised that the answers so far haven't mentioned two factors, neither of them decisive but both relevant.

First, it's not so long ago that left-handed schoolchildren were punished for their 'wilful disobedience' in writing with the wrong hand; this was either because they made the rows of children writing at desks look untidy or because, with fountain pens universal, covering the new words with your hand (as lefties do in left-to-right writing) causes smudges. [Choose your preferred explanation: both can be found in convincing sources].

And mediaeval heraldry used the *bar sinister* as a mark of illegitimacy.  'Sinister' here meant only 'starting from the left, the unusual side', and the mark was a practical and non-judgmental "document" in pre-literate times.  Fathers and legitimate children, however, saw such people as a threat to their position, and thought them unpleasant if not positively sinister.

Answer (score 5):

Please permit me to add to the other helpful answers by partially extracting from further references; please read the links for the complete content. I have not extracted from http://www.word-detective.com/2012/01/right-left/ to save space, but it may aid.

Linguistics SE also features [this](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/2555/5306) similar question.

---

[By Prof Anatoly Liberman](http://blog.oup.com/2010/09/left-hand/)

There is something righteous about the right hand: it is supposed to point in the right direction and do everything right.  In older Indo-European, even a special word existed for “right hand,” as evidenced by Greek *dexios* (stress on the last syllable), Latin *dexter*, and others.  A strong association connects the right hand with the south and the left hand with the north.  Someone standing with his face turned to the rising sun (for example, while praying), will have his right hand stretched to the south and his left hand to the north.  Old Irish *tuath* meant both “north” and “left” (when facing east).  This case is not unique.  Here is a variant of the most common definition of “left” in our dictionaries: “Connected with that part of the body which is situated to the west when one faces north.” Compare *right*: “straight, direct, not curved or bent; further from the main part of the heart.”  In an old post on the etymology of *north*, I discussed the tie between the concepts “left” and “north” and the possibility of explaining north as meaning “left.”  If Sanskrit *naraka-* “the kingdom of the dead” is related to Engl. *north* (which is uncertain), we can assume that in the opinion of the ancient Indians the Other Word was a cold place, rather than hell with its eternal fire, frying pans, and boiling pots, as we see it in medieval European pictures.  Reference to “down” in north and some words for “left” cannot be excluded either.  But the most noticeable thing is the paucity of Indo-European words for “right hand,” as opposed to the abundance of names coined for its opposite.

[...] [See more at: http://blog.oup.com/2010/09/left-hand/#sthash.X691KeE8.dpuf]

---

[In the study of origins, it was always better to be "right" than wrong, or even "left"!](http://wordinfo.info/unit/3777/s:and)

Words associated with the right side are generally complimentary or have signified something desirable, but those pointing to the left are quite the opposite. For example, even in modern times, everyone tries to get up on the "right" side of the bed and hopes to stay on the "right" side of one's boss; that is, if the person is in his/her "right" mind.

Other languages reflect the same bias in favor of the right and against the left. In Latin, the word for "right" is ***dexter***, from which has come the English word *dexterous* or *dextrous*; meaning "skillful". This is what a person who uses the "right" hand is expected to be.

An *ambidextrous* person should be even more skillful, since he is described as having two "right hands.

On the other hand, the Latin ***sinister*** is the left hand, that is, the wrong hand. Furthermore, left-handers were thought to be unlucky.

In Roman augury, or fortune telling, birds that appeared on the left side were interpreted as being bad luck; however, those on the right side presaged good luck. Now, in modern English applications, *sinister* means evil or ominous. [...]

Answer (score 3):

To add to the many other answers, before the introduction of toilet paper, the convention was to eat with the right hand and to clean up after using the toilet with the left.  There are many examples of left hands and left-handedness being seen negatively as a result of that.

There is a folk-etymology that "cack-handed" (meaning clumsy or left-handed) refers to this, the dialect word "cack" referring to faeces.

Comment: I believe this explanation is widely accepted by anthropologist who have had the opportunity to see the left-hand-toilet-paper in action.

Answer (score 1):

In the old days, abnormality was considered vile and dangerous. One example is how the music from Middle Ages had only Melody in their music and not Harmony. This was because Christian churches only used one Melody for music. They were very much against unusual things like left-handedness and Magic.

Comment: But surely the music of the spheres was referred to as 'the heavenly harmony'?

Comment: I think those fall under different definitions of _harmony_.

Comment: Is that true? Please can you provide citations? Certainly Bach, a church organist, used both hands to great effect.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Johann Sebastian Bach (1685-1750) is not medieval by any stretch of the definition. The Middle Ages in Europe were roughly 500-1500, where the end date fluctuates depending on context etc, but commonly in arts defined as the emergence of the Renaissance, which preceded the Baroque period of Bach. Anyway, I agree that this answer is neither here nor there as an answer to the actual question, especially without citations or references.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago, an attorney friend w/a history background, told me 'sinister', and, therefore,'sinistralian', etc., came from the Roman legion's concern about fighting alongside a left-hander  while in the tortoise formation.

Comment: Plenty of lefties fought in the Roman legions... but with their right hands. You couldn't fight left-handed unless you were an auxiliary.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps not an evolution in or from Latin, but a contribution (in late ancient empire times) to Latin (from remotely ancient, Hebrew times).

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11420/good-inclination-or-evil-inclination-in-the-womb?rq=1

suggests an origin in Judaic scripture and teaching, extending back possibly as far as the Patriarchal era. The concept seems to have related to a connection between heart and mind, the left (sinister) heart harboring innate (embued in the womb) evil influence on the mind; the right (dexter)...the opposite.

In the current, less descriptive, more "scientific" era it might be said that such a "manifestation," whether in belief or in actuality, might rest in the connection and dialog between reasoning and feeling (except with up and down orientations reversed) parts of the brain.

To think that such a concept is considered antiquated (or quaint) in current times is not comprehensively refutable:

Lefthandedness, even within a still living (barely) generation, was held (putting it kindly) to be "not so good" and/or "not well-forboding,"--even so bad as to be a visitation of life misfortune--and was sought to be reversed by training, both in homes and in schools. (...ever see a cursive writing chart showing pencil gripped in curl-around orientation?)

Confused handedness is sometimes observed clinically as a trait of some mentally disabled.

While no physiological, genetic, or congenital reason for abberent (left) handedness has yet been discovered--and left-handedness does not run in families--a clear connection between left handedness and trauma/accident/stress during the pre-handedness phase of fetal or infant development has been documented.

And might we ask if calling a person a southpaw (probably most people do not the source of that word) could have any connection to the term whereby things, luck, situations, prospects (etc) are said to "go sinisterly south"?  (Please don't pounce. Just a supposition...only for fun.)

...if only Kipling were still around, to give the world a kinder-hearted replacement of that particular S word!

PS: Speaking of wombs and modern observations of early life influence on handedness, it certainly seems as if doctors of long-ago times had things to show us today, for which, in this instance, we had the Romans to thank for passing their words forward in time.