# What does "in a sinister light" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The figure of the legislator is a puzzle. Like the tutor in Emile, the
>   legislator has the role of manipulating the desires of his charges,
>   giving them the illusion of free choice without its substance.Little
>   wonder then that many critics have seen these characters **in a somewhat
>   sinister light**.  http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rousseau/

My opinion is that “see someone or something in a sinister light” is not equal to “to consider it as being a sinister thing”, but means that to apprehend something  unfriendly. And usually, when we read this phrase, we will expect some words about the light in which it is seen. Is my explanation correct?

Assuming it is right, suppose I want to say the opposite thing, can I say something like : many interpreters have seen these characters in a sympathetic light? What is the right expression when it comes to use light to express a sympathetic or friendly interpretation of people’s words or character?

Comment: A point I'm surprised nobody has pointed out yet (I found out by searching the page for the string _left_) is that _sinister_ itself means "left-handed" in Latin. And thus all the anti-gaucherie prejudices from several thousand years of righteous rule come home to roost anywhere they're invited. Since _light_ has no handedness, and is being used abstractly via the [`Thought` Is `Light` metaphor theme](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/April05Eye.pdf), only the nasty connotations are being transferred to whatever _light_ means here.

Comment: IANAL (I am not a Latin), but it’s my understanding that *sinister* means simply *left* and not *left-handed*. Sources: [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sinister), [“The Latin Dictionary” (wikidot.com)](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/adjective:sinister), and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter_and_sinister) (whose source is [the Latin Dictionary and Grammar Aid at the University of Notre Dame](http://archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/lookup.pl?stem=sinist&ending=er)); see also [bend sinister (a.k.a. “bar sinister”)](https://www.revolvy.com/topic/bend+heraldry) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and [simchona’s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/39092/26083#39094)  to [Daniel’s question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/39092/26083 "How did “sinister”, the Latin word for “left-handed”, get its current meaning?") (which, for me at least, is Google’s #2 response to [a search for “sinister latin”](https://www.google.com/search?q=sinister+latin)).

Answer (score 3):

That's an abuse of a common expression as an idiom.

The original comes from given type of light exposing or hiding certain features. It can be a flattering light, or unflattering light - light that makes the subject look better or worse. Wear an expensive amethyst collar and show up in light of inexpensive incandescent bulbs. The amethysts look like cheap bottle glass, your skin looks ashen and the shadows under your eyes seem deeper: it's a very unflattering light.

By extension - metaphor/idiom, given light may expose/enhance given features, so "viewing in sinister light" means noticing sinister features of character, have a bias towards noticing negative - evil - sinister qualities. It doesn't outright mean a judgment, but it implies a certain focus, suspicion. Innocent and positive acts may go overlooked, while negative, questionable, risque themes are emphasized.

If you want the opposite, it will be a *positive, friendly, kind* light. If you want to be sarcastic, claiming the light is *overly* kind, you can say about looking at them *through rose-tinted glasses*.

Comment: Do you mean that "in a sinister light" is an idiom and my conjuring up "in a sympathetic light" an abuse, or that "in a sinister light" is an abuse of some other idiom?

Comment: No, "in flattering light" is a common expression, and "in sinister light" abuses that expression making it into an idiom. There are no lamps that shine sinisterly.

Answer (score 1):

There are **two** factors involved in both the original literal expression and various metaphorical usages (**see** X in a Y **light**).

-2. The lighting conditions / plainly observable features obtaining.

-1. The observing by the audience / appraisal by those making a judgement

As an example of where the *light* (rather than any critical bias of any audience) is heavily emphasised (by not mentioning any judges) (ie an objective emphasis):

[NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/08/24/arts/music/international-contemporary-ensemble-mix-old-and-new.html?_r=0)

> But during his lifetime, one popular work cast [Beethoven] in a
>   different light not particularly to his liking.

And, as we shall see, the metaphor has been broadened into 'see X in a Y' light' where Y' need no longer correspond to the original quality of light (flattering / unflattering) but to the interpretation encouraged (sinister etc).

And one that emphasises predisposition of the appraisers (ie a subjective emphasis):

[The Two Faces of Ronald Reagan](https://mises.org/daily/5010)

> Liberals are being soft-soaped into accepting or at least tolerating
>   Reagan, but opponents of big government see him in a different light.

My opinion is that “see someone or something in a sinister light” **is** here likely to be equal to “to consider it as being a sinister thing” - I'm assuming no prejudice (on average) amongst the 'critics' mentioned.

Comment: You have not one hundred percent convinced me with regard to your last opinion, maybe 51% percent already. I think that a critic, say, who questions the legitimacy of the legislator, might be counted as seeing the legislator in sinister light.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure that we're all influenced by previous experiences – often in ways we're not conscious of. That's why Justice has to wear a blindfold ("HIM again!"). Prejudices (sadly) / experience, **and** newly discovered facets (thankfully), both sway a person's judgement. The colour of the light is influenced by both the facet it's reflecting off (objective influence), and the colour of the goggles / spectacles one's wearing (subjective influence).

Comment: This is a great answer. I am satisfied if you mean that our opinions or conclusions about things, all of them, are inevitably affected by our biases. With this logic, the property you attribute to things is the same as that of your prospective throught which you see them, or if not the same, they must be so similiar that you can hardly differentiate them. The sinisterness of your light must pollute your understanding of the object in the light so much that the sinisterness of the light is transferred into the object.

Answer (score -1):

“In a sinister light” means to portray someone or something in a negative manner.