# Right Good but Left Bad

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, aphorism-requests

While examining the definition/etymology of the adjective *sinister*, I noticed its senses of EVIL, ILL-FORTUNE, and general inauspiciousness, as well as explicit references to the noun/adjective LEFT.

A subsequent examination of the definition of the adjective LEFT however, while uniformly negative and pejorative, revealed nothing more sinister or evil than references to the left-hand’s evaluation as the weaker and, I assume, less valuable side of the body, and to liberal, socialist, or radical political ideologies, senses which were established relatively late, being first attested in English 1837. As LEFT is obviously being contrasted with its opposite, I examined the definitions of RIGHT (and, dexter), which associations (no surprise here) are as uniformly positive as LEFT are negative.

The impact exerted upon the English language of this "right-good *vs* left-bad" trope must be vast. **What are some examples of this trope embedded in everyday English - phrases, idioms, aphorisms?**

**Example**: Philippe Petit's conception and execution of his Trade Center Towers performance is arguably the greatest wire walk in history - all of it but the walk itself was accomplished undercover and covertly because **no one in their right mind** would have knowingly allowed Petit to conduct such a suicidal mission ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How did "sinister", the Latin word for "left-handed", get its current meaning?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39092/how-did-sinister-the-latin-word-for-left-handed-get-its-current-meaning)

Comment: The political sense of *left* and *right* is historical accident: it referred originally to the physical locations where the factions clustered in the French National Assembly of 1789 and thereafter. Leftists regard right-wingers with loathing, and vice versa.

Comment: Re: [Offering the left hand](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262318/offering-left-hand/262328#262328). I think you're going to have to go back, further than the invention of English, for this one.

Comment: It’s quite common in Indo-European languages. Irish _deas_ means both ‘good/nice’ and ‘right (side)’, while _clé_ means both ‘sinister, evil, wrong’ and ‘left’. The Scandiwegian _højre/høyre/högra/hægri_ ‘right’ is etymologically the comparative of Old Norse _hœgr_ ‘convenient, appropriate’, i.e., ‘the better one’ (though its opposite, _venstre/vänster/vinstri_ ‘left’ etymologically means ‘the friendlier one’, which is also positive—likely euphemistic, though). French _droit_ means ‘correct’ as well as ‘right’, and its opposite _gauche_ ‘left’ also means the same as in English.

Comment: @JakeRegier That's a good read for how and of what *right/left* took their meanings, but not *why* (other than to hint at religious reasoning). *"In Sanskrit, the word "वाम" (waama) stands for both "left" and "wicked."* –[Bias against left-handed people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_against_left-handed_people), Wiki

Comment: @Mazura Does this excerpt from an answer to that question not provide one such possible answer to this question? "One way auspices would use to guess good and bad omens was to watch which direction some auspicious types of birds like ravens, crows or eagles were flying by. These birds were supposed to play the role of messengers of the gods. ... If birds were flying by on your right this was good omen. On the left (sinistra) that was bad omen."

Comment: @JakeRegier Yes, but why is it *"left bad, right good"*? The point I'm trying to avoid (because I like this question) is that it's answer will not be found *untranslated* into English. It will rely on cultural interpretations of a dead language.

Comment: @Mazura Again, as posited on the possible duplicate, "right handed people have a natural tendency to associate negative sensations to their left-hand side." This directly mirrors the answer below that has been up-voted by the asker, which leads me to believe that the two questions are too closely related to be considered different.

Comment: @Mazura & .@JakeRegier, I appreciate the dialogue y'all are having and the information is provocative, also I'd love it if you would compose formal answers for your respective intuitions. It seems to me that the status right/positive & left/negative is pervasive and it's origins sweep back into the mists of time. I'd not only appreciate thoughts on the origin of this dichotomy, but additionally articulations of this dichotomy that are embedded and obscured in everyday English words, phrases, idioms, aphorisms. Thanks.

Comment: I have (also) already answered elsewhere that [all roads lead to the latrine]. Speaking of which, that question deserves to be un-held if *this* one is valid.

Comment: @LittleEva Understood, and perhaps I will. However, I question your most recent edit, *"when I wrote right/positive & left/negative I immediately thought of electricity, and battery terminals,"*  as electricity has nothing to do with *left* and *right*.

Comment: Your question has already been addressed here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39092/how-did-sinister-the-latin-word-for-left-handed-get-its-current-meaning. See Alain Pannetier's answer.

Comment: The association with the scooter terminals is poetic at best.  There is no relationship between the positive and negative terminals of any battery and good or bad.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a global, cross-cultural, multi-lingual historic trend, not about English *per se*.

Comment: (I suppose I could have gone with "too broad", but that didn't really do the question justice.)

Comment: I agree with Hellion.  In any case, this has already been addressed in another post, which I linked in my answer (which got a negative vote, surprisingly.)

Comment: Little Eva, the terms negative and positive on a battery were coined long before people associated positive with good and negative with bad.  There were negative numbers before electricity was a topic of interest, and people didn't think of them as bad or evil, they were simply necessary extensions with which to progress further with mathematical ideas...same with irrationals and transcendentals and imaginary numbers.

Comment: @michael_timofeev, might as well get over being surprised at down-votes, rather they're to be expected. Even the most highly up-voted Q&A's will get a couple, almost without fail. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Too broad, and you haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: examples of a "leftist" idiom and one proverb: 1. [left-handed compliment](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/left-handed+compliment) and 2. [A wise man’s heart inclines him to the right, but a fool’s heart to the left.](http://biblehub.com/ecclesiastes/10-2.htm)

Answer (score 6):

This dichotomy is surprisingly pervasive in language. It shows up not just in English, but in Sanskrit, most Slavic languages, French, German, Dutch, Irish, Finnish, Swedish, Hungarian, Turkish, Chinese, Korean, and Hebrew.

There are some great examples located in the [Disparaging associations in language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_against_left-handed_people#Disparaging_associations_in_language) section on Wikipedia.

---

Warning: this is just my speculation...

> Considering [roughly 10% of the population is left-handed](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/263/1377/1627?ijkey=72fd76d2d123ded28960a5ffede3dece6a117974&keytype2=tf_ipsecsha), the explanation of this prejudice may be as "simple" as longstanding subjugation of a minority group. While that may play a part in the matter, the even simpler fact of life for many people living in developing nations is the designation of one hand for wiping, so that the other may stay unpolluted and be used for eating. This mores dates back to primordial civilizations as well, and may be a reason for such a ubiquitous slant on right and left.

Comment: Thank you for your response (+1), I suspect that it's just as likely that the esteem accorded all things RIGHT determined the utilization for employing the LEFT-hand for such a base activity, than the other way around.

Comment: +1 for the wiping thing.  People had to do that with one hand or the other, and the stronger one was often occupied.  Also you would eventually have to shake hands with someone and hope they were raised to wipe with their left.  Oh, and I'm a lefty.

Comment: @LittleEva If it were the case that there is no genetic difference (right is not dominant, left not recessive, and therefore right is no more common, stronger, more likely to be used for esteemed activities, etc.), then I would be inclined to agree with you. If there is a [gene that controls handedness](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/why-are-some-people-left-handed-6556937/?no-ist) (or more likely, a conflation of genes), then things would get pretty darn complicated. This conversation strayed from English quite a bit, but is very interesting to chew on.

Answer (score 2):

**Handshake** –[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshake)

> **Social Chemosignaling**
>
> It has been discovered as a part of a research in the Weizmann Institute, that human handshakes serve as a mean of transferring social chemical signals between the shakers. It appears that there is a tendency to bring the shaken hands to the vicinity of the nose and perform an olfactory sampling of it. This may serve an evolutionary need to learn about the person whose hand was shaken, replacing a more overt and less socially acceptable sniffing behavior, as common in other animals.

We humans, have been shaking each others hands for a very long time and, unlike other mammals that are more flexible, have to [clean ourselves](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262318/offering-left-hand/262328#262328) with our hands. I surmise the simple *idea* of *'the wrong hand'* for a job, in a society where dexterity favors one side with an almost complete bias, to predate language in all of its forms.

> In **Sanskrit**, the word "वाम" (waama) stands for both "left" and "wicked." –[Bias against left-handed people, Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_against_left-handed_people)
>
> In **Chinese** culture, the adjective "left" sometimes means "improper" or "out of accord". For instance, the phrase "left path" stands for unorthodox or immoral means.

IMO, the etymology lies in cultural practices that arose before recorded history.

Re: *other ways the left/right thing has affected our language and culture* -probably more than I'm willing to speculate, considering the trope can be found in almost all religions and languages.

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort Mazura, that *Social Chemosignaling* research is kind of shocking, while at the same time perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the dichotomy depends on their etymology. It appears that  *Left*  derives its negative meaning from heraldry:

[Sinister](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sinister):

> - Meaning "evil" is from late 15c. ***Used in heraldry from 1560s to indicate "left, to the left." Bend (not "bar") sinister in heraldry indicates illegitimacy*** and preserves the literal sense of "on or from the left side" (though in heraldry this is from the view of the bearer of the shield, not the observer of it).

while [dexterity](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dexterity&allowed_in_frame=0):

> - 1520s, from Middle French dexterité (16c.),***from Latin dexteritatem (nominative dexteritas) "readiness, skillfulness, prosperity," from dexter "skillful," also "right (hand)" (source of Old French destre, Spanish diestro, etc.)*** The Latin form is with the comparative suffix -ter, thus meaning etymologically "the better direction." Middle English dester meant "right hand," and in heraldry dexter means "on the right side."