# Word for someone who discriminates against left handed people

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology, pejorative-language

We have words like racist, bigot, xenophobe, etc. that we are all familiar with, but what would we call someone who discriminates against left handed people?

Comment: I did not realize that discrimination against lefties was even existent.

Comment: @NathanM. the discrimination is apparent even in the adjectives for "left" that English has borrowed: Latin "sinister" and French "gauche".

Comment: Those words aren’t discriminatory, and they have nothing to do with left-handed people.

Comment: @NathanM. You can find the word "sinister" meaning "left" in older works: ["in his sinister hand"](https://books.google.com/books?id=dnIABAAAQBAJ&pg=PA325&dq=%22+In+his+Sinister-Hand%22.). The original association came from Latin (see also [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/39094/191178)). Although "sinister" dropped the meaning of "left" centuries ago (except in heraldry), people were still forcing leftie children to write with their rights until pretty recently, with  [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3258574/) saying it was common til the 60s.